# How to set text at one page and image at another page in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

In my iPad app. I'm working on UIPageViewController I want to set text at one page and image at another page. I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution.  It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

I have used the code which is there in below link

http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/

here is the sample code. i used contentviewcontroller.

i want to use two view controllers with UIPageViewController

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
               spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation

{

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))

{
    //Set the array with only 1 view controller
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    //Important- Set the doubleSided property to NO.
    self.pageViewController.doubleSided = NO;
    //Return the spine location
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;

}
else
{
    NSArray *viewControllers = nil;
    ContentViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)currentViewController labelContents]];

     NSUInteger currentIndex2 = [self.imagesArray2 indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)currentViewController imageContents]];

    if(currentIndex == 0 || currentIndex %2 == 0 || currentIndex2 == 0||currentIndex2 %2 == 0)
    {
        UIViewController *nextViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentViewController, nextViewController, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIViewController *previousViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousViewController, currentViewController, nil];
    }
    //Now, set the viewControllers property of UIPageViewController
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
```

}

Comment: please post code that you have tried so far....

Comment: How are you setting text and image?

Comment: i have edited the question with a link which i had used in my code. please go through it.

Comment: @Learner please go through the link

Comment: @fibnochi please go through the link.

Comment: your code is working. but i have 10 images and image contents(text)  in the left side i want to display image contents and in the right side i want display images. I used your code but only 5 images displayed in the right side and only 5 image contents displayed in the left side.  remaining are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps can be helpful

1. Keep UILabel and and UIImageView in ContentViewController
2. Add UIImage OR NSString in the modelArray.
3. When you make a new ContantViewController check if object in model is image or string using following.


   `if ([myObject class] == [UIImage class])

   {

   //HERE ASSIGN IT TO UIIMAGEVIEW.image

   }

   else

   {

   //HERE ASSIGN IT TO UILABEL.text

   }`

post if you need more help....

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for.....

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well then add an imageView in ContentPageView.xib file and make an outlet of. Set ImageView and label hidden or visible on your required pages.